# Custom Search Page Pagination Not Working

Tags: pages, pagination, search, paginate-links

My Seach Page URLs:

> https://www.example.com/search/keyword/page/2/

Here my custom search page:

```
<?php 

    if($_GET['search_text'] && !empty($_GET['search_text']))
    {
        $text = $_GET['search_text'];
    }
    else
    {
        $text = urldecode( get_query_var('search_text') ) ;            
    }

?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">            
        <div class="searchpage-container">
            <div class="searchpage-filter-container">
                <span>Arama Sonuçları:</span>
            </div>                
            <div class="product-container">
                <?php
                    $my_products = array( 2085, 4094, 2900, 4072, 131 );

                    global $paged;
                    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'posts_per_page' => 2,
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'post__in' => $my_products

                    );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                        endwhile;

                        $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

                        if ($total_pages > 1){

                            /* $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged')); */
                            $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current_page = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current_page = 1;   
                            echo $wp_query->query_vars['paged'];

                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                'format' => '/page/%#%',
                                'current' => $current_page,
                                'total' => $total_pages,
                                'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                                'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                            ));
                        }
                    } 
                    wp_reset_postdata();                    

                ?>  
            </div>            
        </div>


    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

My pagination links are created fine, but I always see the page No 1 because somehow `query_vars['paged']` is emtpy.

I have seen `Preserving Search Page Results and Pagination` section on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) , but couldn't figure it out how to use it, but I don't think this is really needed in my case.

**EDIT 1 (Response to comment from J.D.):**

That function you mentioned only returns an array of product IDs, to simplify my code, I removed my function add a static array instead.

Comment: What is the code of `aws_search_byozan()`? Could it be overwriting the `paged` query var? If you `get_query_var( 'paged' )` _before_ calling that, what is the value?

Comment: @J.D. I updated my question based on your response, and removed `aws_search_byozan()` from code. Problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a conflict between your replacement query and the default search query that's running behind the scenes.

Instead of running a new WP_Query, try modifying the default query by hooking to pre_get_posts:

```
function wpse276396_search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $text = urldecode( get_query_var('search_text') );
      $my_products = aws_search_byozan($text);
      $query->set('post_type', 'product');
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
      $query->set('post__in', $my_products);
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse276396_search_filter');
```

Then you'd output the default Loop in your template instead of your custom WP_Query Loop.

This has the advantage of not hitting the database once for the default query then disregarding the results and using your custom query to render the page instead, plus the `paged` and `posts_per_page` arguments are consistent with what WP expects.

**Edit: I somehow managed to miss that this is in a page template.** That's enough WPSE for me for today, but I'll update my answer to reflect that rather than modifying the default search query (which is still a better option unless you need your custom search to coexist with the built-in search form).

In this case what's happening is WP is expecting the `paged` and `posts_per_page` arguments to apply to the main query which fetched your search Page, which means the instructions on the Codex page you linked absolutely do apply.

```
$my_products = aws_search_byozan($text);
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

if( strlen($query_string) > 0 ) {
    foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
        $query_split = explode("=", $string);
        $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
    } // foreach
} //if

global $paged;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__in' => $my_products

);
$loop = new WP_Query( array_merge($search_query, $args ) );
```

Comment: Note that you could just use `wp_parse_str()` instead of splitting the `$query_string` manually. I've updated the codex example to do this, as it is  much simpler.

Comment: Not sure whether I should leave my answer as-is because it's the version OP saw originally or update it to match the updated Codex. Thoughts?

Comment: I think it is good to improve an answer, although if the change is substantial you might want to let the OP know. In this case though, I wouldn't think that is necessary, since the result should be the same as before; it doesn't actually change the code's behavior. Of course, if you don't update the answer people will still see my comment. But if you do update it I can remove my comments and reduce clutter. :-)

Comment: hi chris, Its okey for me if you update your answer, I can find the previous version from your edited section. I am currently analysing your solution, not tested yet.

Comment: @ChrisCox when I implemented your system, it did not change anything and I debugged and realized something. `Paged` was even not inside the `$query_string`, which made me think that my URL rediraction has some problems. So I have checked my `add_rewrite_rule`, and saw that I did not send paged as a paramter. So I have edited it and everything fixed, and it works even without codes above with it's inital state. Your answer here does not my exact answer, but you showed me the way by `$query_string` which I was not aware of before, I'll give you the bounty. @J.D. thank you for your help too.

Answer (score 1):

for this problem you first use a pagination function like this :

```
 function cupagenavi() {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
$pages = '';
$max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if (!$current = get_query_var('paged')) $current = 1;
$a['base'] = ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks()) ? user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 'page', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . '?page=%#%', 'page' ) : @add_query_arg('page','%#%');
if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $a['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
$a['total'] = $max;
$a['current'] = $current;
$total = 1;
$a['mid_size'] = 4;
$a['end_size'] = 4;
$a['prev_text'] = 'Previous Page';
$a['next_text'] = 'Next Page';
if ($max > 1) echo '';
echo $pages . paginate_links($a);
if ($max > 1) echo '';
}
```

for using this function use this code

```
if (function_exists('cupagenavi')) cupagenavi();
```

and then in your query post use :

```
$paged = $_GET['page'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not fully clear which 'paged' variable you refer, because you have it in different places.

actually, instead of `$wp_query->get..` you should try  $loop or $GLOBALS['wp_query']

//sent from mobile,sorry for grammar